# Переходность глагола

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос. Проясните, пожалуйста, ситуацию. Исходя из теории, глаголы, которые сочетаются или могут сочетаться с существительным или местоимением в винительном падеже без предлога, называются переходными.Вопрос по конкретному глаголу - "перелететь". Некоторые считают его непереходным, т.к. без предлога здесь никак не обойтись:перелететь обязательно через кого, что. Это верно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глагол ***''перелететь''*** может быть как ***переходным , так и непереходным.*** 
***Обратимся к словарю.*** ПЕРЕЛЕТЕТЬ, -лечу, -летишь; св. 1. (кого-что или через что). 
Летя, преодолеть какое-л. пространство, оказаться по другую сторону чего-л. ***П. море. П.*** ***через Альпы.*** Самолёт, вертолёт перелетает из Москвы в Петербург за час. ***П. линию фронта.*** // Переместиться по воздуху от толчка, броска на какое-л. расстояние. ***П. через руль велосипеда.*** Каскадёр перелетел на мотоцикле через преграду. ***Акробат перелетел на противоположную трапецию.*** 2. Летя, переместиться куда-л. Птицы перелетели с севера на юг. Ворона перелетела на крышу. Попугайчик перелетел на карниз. П. в воздухе, по воздуху. П. с места на место. 3. Разг. Стремительно перепрыгнуть, перебежать, переехать через что-л. Белка перелетела с дерева на дерево. П. через ров. Лошади перелетели через мост. 4. Распространиться из одного места в другое (о слухах, вестях и т.п.). Слух о голоде перелетит из города в город. Весть об убийстве мгновенно перелетела в другой город. 5. Летя, упасть слишком далеко, дальше, чем следует. ***Снаряд перелетел цель.*** 
 Перелетать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Перелетание, -я; ср.

> ***Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
> Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.***

Comment: То есть надо смотреть по контексту? Если "с ветки на ветку перелететь", то здесь глагол непереходный?

Comment: Да, вы правы: все зависит от контекста. Однако стоить помнить, что не все глаголы, после которых дополнение стоит в винительном падеже, являются переходными. Ср. напр.: **простоять час (в очереди) или жить неделю (на море)** , где глаголы не являются переходными, хотя после них и стоят существительные в винительном падеже без предлога: Всю ночь (В. п. со значением времени, а не объекта) гремел (глагол непереходный) овраг соседний, ручей, бурля, бежал к ручью (А. Фет) . Переходные глаголы обозначают действие направленное непосредственно на предмет.

Comment: Глаголы, которые не могут иметь при себе прямого дополнения, являются непереходными: заниматься (чем? ) спортом, разбираться (в чём? ) в музыке, отказаться (от чего? ) от помощи. 
Важно также знать, что **переходность/непереходность** тесно связана с лексическим значение глагола: в одном значении глагол может быть переходным, а в другом — непереходным. Ср. : Я говорю правду (говорю — ''высказываю'' — переходный глагол) . Ребёнок уже говорит (говорит — ''разговаривает" — неп.гл) ; Завтра я поеду од­на, буду учить (непереходный глагол) в школе <..> (А. Чехов) ; учить уроки (п/г глагол).